# Is bottled green tea just as beneficial as loose leaf green tea from tea shops?

Tags: cancer, herpes, cholesterol, drug-withdrawal, hiv

There's a tasty and cheap, cold bottle of green tea that I've been buying daily for 2.75 per bottle.  Most grocery stores sell it.

It is unsweetened, supposedly made from loose leaf tea and has lots of vitamin C.

Tea shops would charge about 4 or 5 dollars for a large iced green tea, and tea rooms charge even more - like a 8 to 12 dollars.

Am I getting the same health benefits from this bottled green tea?

Comment: Your question rests on a vague assumption that there are health benefits to green tea. Which specific benefits?